# Differences between two files

Tags: python, bash

I am connecting to a remote machine, and saving the outputs of two queries in two different files and take the results the new results that appear today:

Having two files:

**yesterday.txt**

```
AAA=1
BBB=2
CCC=3
```

**today.txt**

```
AAA=1
BBB=2
DDD=3
EEE=2
```

The output of the script should be something like this:

```
WARNING: DIFFERENCES: DDD=3, EEE=2;
```

How could I take this difference?

I have tried with the "diff" command from my Python script, but it seems like it is buggy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ.compare) library:

```
from difflib import Differ

# AAA=1
# BBB=2
# CCC=3
with open("yeterday.txt","r") as f1:
    text1 = f1.read()

# AAA=1
# BBB=2
# DDD=3
# EEE=2
with open("today.txt","r") as f2:
    text2 = f2.read()


d = Differ()
result = list(d.compare(text1, text2))


#   A  A  A  =  1  
#   B  B  B  =  2  
# - C- C- C+ D+ D+ D  =  3+ 
# + E+ E+ E+ =+ 2
print(''.join(result))

# Printing the desired message if difference was detected
output_list = ''.join([diff_char.replace('+ ', '').replace(' +', '') for diff_char in difflib.ndiff(text1, text2) if '+' in diff_char[0]])

if output_list:
    # WARNING: DIFFERENCES:
    # DDD
    # EEE=2
    print(f'WARNING: DIFFERENCES:\n{output_list}')
```

Comment: you suold use with statement in order to read a file or REMBER to close it when you are done